# Eclipse Android: Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700)

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, virtual-machine, ddms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800386/could-not-open-selected-vm-debug-port-8700)

I am getting this error on the console when opening `Eclipse`:

> "Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700). Make sure you do not have >another instance of DDMS or of the eclipse plugin running. If it's being >used by something else, choose a new port number in the preferences."

pretty sure `DDMS` is the Andoid debugger, and I am also pretty sure it is not turned on. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Easiest solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/31159313/1925394

Answer (score 25):

```
the window Host file that is messed up:
the file is at this place :
C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc

And should contain this line : 127.0.0.1 localhost
```

if it doesn't work then try the following as well:
make the following changes in Eclipse.

Under Window -> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS:

```
* Set Base local debugger port to "8601"
* Check the box that says "Use ADBHOST" and the value should be "127.0.0.1"
```

Comment: @Peter how do you do this on a mac?

Comment: On mac - you should press on the Eclipse button in the top menu bar and then press on Preferences -> Android - >DDMS

Answer (score 1):

its is a eclipse perspective so you don't need to start it just click on  the >> button on the topmost right corner you can see other perspective select DDMS there DDMS perspective will open if you want to switch back click on java perspective. If you can't see DDMS option there just go to Windows->openPerspective->others and from the dialog box select DDMS.

To activate DDMS you need to run your application in debug mode and then click on ddms you will see all options once your application started.

hope this help

Comment: I see that - i am still getting this error though - ideas? "[2010-11-01 12:36:45 - ddms]Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700). Make sure you do not have another instance of DDMS or of the eclipse plugin running. If it's being used by something else, choose a new port number in the preferences."

Comment: try using different port no as per ur error message says I think it should work

Answer (score 1):

Try by changing Run-> Debug Configuration. It helped me to activate breakpoint and debugging. After changing options there is debug button click on it. It will attach debugger and launch your application.