# Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700). Make sure you do not have another instance of DDMS or of the eclipse plugin running

Tags: android, debugging, virtual-machine, port, ddms

I'm trying to execute an android program in eclipse kepler. However, every time I execute I get this message. I did what everyone said about this problem like:

  - Making sure there is a line on windows Host file that contain this line:
  `127.0.0.1 localhost`
  - Going to
  `Window -> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS`
  and:
    1. Setting local debugger port to 8601
    2. Check the box
    `Use ADBHOST`
    and the value should be
    `127.0.0.1`

However, none of these things fixed my problem.

Note: I'm using windows 8.1.

Answer (score 4):

two instance of adb.exe are started.

> Solve it by Open Task manager by pressing Ctrl+Shift +DEl

and  **ending the process "adb.exe"**

Answer (score 1):

I am currently having this issue too.

My problems arose from the fact that I am trying to run Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA at the same time. this is because at the moment the logcat view in eclipse appears to be showing me more information, especially when my apps are failing.

I realised that even if you change the "DDMS port" to say 10600, javaw will always be running on port 8700.

Also,when i start IDEA alone, even if its DDMSis on port 8600, i have idea.exe running on port 8700.

So, i feel, this javaw is the one responsible for allowing our debuggers to run. havent solved further though, but for my case, when i start eclipse alone, or first before starting IDEA, everything works perfectly.

Comment: thank you for your help. But I change the program for programming android app to Android Studio