# Debugging problem with the Android SDK on Eclipse

Tags: linux, debugging, android-emulator, port, ubuntu-10.10

I'm trying to open my debugger for an Android project.  The emulator opens fine, but the debugger is hanging and thus never fully loads.  I keep getting this message, that never goes away:

"Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.example.android.myApp' on port 8616"  (The connection never completes).

I am using Linux Ubuntu 10.10.

Thank you all for your help. :)
Matt

Answer (score 0):

set the following flad in your `AndroidManifest.xml` in the tag `application`

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

Note following Article: [Eclipse Android: Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045645/eclipse-android-could-not-open-selected-vm-debug-port-8700)

This aswell: [Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800386/could-not-open-selected-vm-debug-port-8700)