# Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700) in eclipse

Tags: android

When I am opening eclipse I am getting an error " Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700). Make sure you do not have another instance of DDMS or of the eclipse plugin running. If it's being used by something else, choose a new port number in the preferences." I tried certain links in stackoverflow, but not solve the issue. Please help me. I refered this "[Eclipse Android: Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045645/eclipse-android-could-not-open-selected-vm-debug-port-8700)" not working for me. I cannot able to compile in emulator because of this.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800386/could-not-open-selected-vm-debug-port-8700?rq=1

Comment: Windows 7 operating system